# Autofilling shipping info from profile model into template

Tags: django-models, django-forms, django-templates, profile

I am trying to auto fill shipping info if they have an address saved to their profile model when someone makes an order.

```
class Profile(models.Model):
  user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="uname")
  shipping = models.ForeignKey(Shipping, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=true)

class Shipping(models.Model):
  full_name=models.CharField(_("Full Name"), max_length=256)
  street_address=models.CharField(_("Street Address"), max_length=1024)
  address_2=models.CharField(_("Address 2"), max_length=1024)
  city=models.CharField(_("City"), max_length=128
  state=models.CharField(_("State"), max_length=2)
  zip_code=models.CharField(_("Zip Code"), max_length=10)
```

I tried loading it into the html manually like

```
<input type="text" value="{{profile.shipping.street_address}}"><input>
```

And also into a widget like

```
class ShippingForm(forms.ModelForm):
  class Meta:
    model=Shipping
    fields = "__all__"

    widgets = {
      'street_address': forms.TextInput(attrs={'value': Shipping.street_address}),
    }
```

Neither option will load info from the shipping model into the text fields. Is there any way to do that?

I added code up there above

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do this in your `ModelForm`. Indeed, the `ModelForm` looks like:

```
class ShippingForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Shipping
        fields = '__all__'

        widgets = {
            'street_address': forms.TextInput(),
        }
```

In the view, you can then construct a form with the instance, so:

```
my_instance = None  # Shipping instance
form = ShippingForm(instance=my_instance)
```

This will read the fields from the `my_instance` model object, and fill the values into the form.

Comment: Thank you, I also got it to work the <input> method, I guess I was sending an empty instance in my views. But I fixed it and it started working